# Extraction of elements from summary objects

Tags: r

I have run many regressions in R and I have saved the results in summary objects. For example, I have run:

```
reg1<-lm(v1~w1 +w2+w3+w4, data=dataset.to.r)
summary(reg1) 

reg2<-lm(v2~w1 +w2+w3+w4, data=dataset.to.r)
summary(reg2)
```

etc for 50 variables.

Now I want to extract the coefficients and the R^2 from the summary objects and create a table with them and their significance levels (in Excel if possible):

```
   w1 w2 w3 w4 R^2

v1

v2

v3

.
.

v50
```

Is there a way to do so with a few commands without having to copy paste all values manually? Please notice that I am very new in R and I am not allowed to download and install additional packages.

Comment: Are your models `reg1, reg2, ...` stored in a list, or just scattered in your workspace?

Comment: you can extract your the coefficients etc. as `reg1$coefficients`. loop through your regressions and collect that into a matrix or dataframe. Save as csv using `write.csv` which is a format that can be read by excel.

Comment: @ nrussell, thanks for the reply. I am very new in R, so I am not perfectly sure what you mean. My code is just what I wrote in the question, a sequence of regX, summary(regX) pairs. So I guess they are scattered in the workplace.

Comment: @ mts, thanks for the reply. could you please provide some code for what you are proposing? It seems that could solve the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like the t-stats for each `reg`?

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune, I was thinking to have them as stars (depending on the level of significance), if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple regressions use this:

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mget(ls(pattern='reg')), function(x) x$coefficients))
write.csv(res[,-1], "regression_test.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have tried it, but it is not exactly what I need (or I don't implement it right, it is possible :) ) When I tried it on two regression, the second regression results were written on top of the first results. So I had only the second regression results. Also, I have the w variables as rows, while I would like them as columns (because I have 50 different v-dependent variables).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried it and now has the right format, thank you. Is there a way to include the stars corresponding to significance levels?

Comment: It will most likely need to be calculated separately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your objects are scattered around your workspace as nrussell pointed out. something like

```
obj = mget(ls(pattern="reg"))
```

should give you a list of objects. Now loop through those

```
out = matrix(NA, nrow = 50, ncol=5)
counter = 1
for(o in obj){
  out[counter, 1:4] = o$coefficients[2:5]
  out[counter, 5] = summary(o)$r.squared
  counter = counter+1
}
write.csv(out, "yourfilename.csv")
```

please notice that you are throwing away the intercept of your fits (thats why I index 2:5), is that your intention?

Comment: thanks a lot you for the reply. yes, intercepts are not to be included.

Comment: Let me thank you again. I tried it for two regressions (as an example), but for the first regression I get NA, while the regression has regular coefficients. It also reverses the sequence of the regressions, i.e. the second regression appears first and the second first.

Comment: i have no influence on the ordering of the objects but maybe all you need to do is inverting the row order of `out` before exporting, give it a try. About the NAs, I'd need to see your data here, but maybe you can also try with `summary(o)$coefficients[...]`. Is it ok for the second regression?

Comment: Is there a way to add stars regarding the significance levels, and not just the coefficient?